# Check user input for errors elegantly

Tags: c++, if-statement, error-handling

My program waits for user input, and when appropriate, will process it. I need to check the user input to make sure it fulfils certain criteria, and if it doesn't fulfil all of those criteria it will be rejected.

Pseudo-code is something like:

```
if (fulfills_condition_1)
{
    if (fulfills_condition_2)
    {
        if (fulfills_condition_3)
        {
            /*process message*/
        }
        else
            cout << error_message_3; //where error_message_1 is a string detailing error
    }
    else
        cout << error_message_2; //where error_message_2 is a string detailing error
}
else
    cout << error_message_1; //where error_message_3 is a string detailing error
```

There is the possibility that the number of these conditions could increase, and I was wondering if there was a neater way to represent this  using a switch or something like that instead of lots of cascading `if` statements.

I know there is the possibility of using

```
if (fulfills_condition_1 && fulfills_condition_2 && fulfills_condition_3)
    /*process message*/
else
    error_message; //"this message is not formatted properly"
```

but this is less useful than the first, and does not say where the issue is.

The conditions can roughly be arranged in increasing importance i.e. checking for `condition_1` is more important than checking for `condition_3`, so the `if` statements do work - but is there a better way in general for doing this?

Comment: Have you considered negative-condition checks with a try-catch and an exception class that accurately reflects the condition that tripped the problem in the first place?

Comment: It depends on how complex your input is going to get. I would create a  DSL to declare how input is valid, and create objects representing that DSL, and then say validate this input.

Comment: @PeterWood That is some intense error checking!

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Well, sometimes duplicated code just gets unmaintainable.

Comment: thank you all for your help, this has been very useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
if (!fulfills_condition_1) throw BadInput(error_message_1);
if (!fulfills_condition_2) throw BadInput(error_message_2);
if (!fulfills_condition_3) throw BadInput(error_message_3);

/* process message */
```

Then your exception handler can report the error message, and retry or abort as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

If what bothers you are the cascading `if`s, you could go for one of the following:

Using a boolean:

```
bool is_valid = true;
string error = "";
if (!condition_one) {
  error = "my error";
  is_valid = false;
}

if (is_valid && !condition_two) {
  ...
}

...

if (!is_valid) {
  cout << error;
} else {
  // Do something with valid input
}
```

Using exceptions:

```
try {
  if (!condition_one) {
    throw runtime_error("my error");
  }

  if (!condition_two) {
    ...
  }

  ...

} catch (...) {
  // Handle your exception here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can use "early return" technique:

```
  if (!fulfills_condition_1)
     // error msg here.
     return;

  // fulfills_condition1 holds here.

  if (!fulfills_condition_2)
     // error msg here.
     return;

  // Both conditon1 and condition2 hold here.

  if (!fulfills_condition_3)
     // error msg here.
     return.
```

Answer (score 1):

If this was going to be reused in a few places, I would make a DSL:

```
Validator inputType1Validator =
    Validator.should(fulfill_condition_1, error_message_1)
             .and(fulfill_condition_2, error_message_2)
             .and(fulfill_condition_3, error_message_3)

inputType1Validator.check(input);
```